# Merge two lists that are generated by a python code

Tags: python, list, merge, set

I know we can merge two lists by using something like `final_list= list1 + list2` but if the lists are generated by a python code and they don't have a variable associated with them like list1 and list2, how can we merge them? Say, my code does something like `print output` to give:

```
[1,2,3,4]
[2,0,5,6]
```

I'd like to merge them so I can get unique values using set(final_list). But how do I get the final_list?

PS- My code can return multiple lists. It is not restricted to two.

Comment: Are those lists generated by functions?

Comment: store them in a  variable them....If they are generated from a function, use return at the end of the function instead of print and then you can store the lists

Comment: If you `print` something and don't save it anywhere, it's gone. If you want to work with it later, save it to a variable.

Comment: @thefourtheye yes they are generated by a function.

Comment: Does the function use a `return` statement?

Comment: @Zizouz212 yes it does.

Comment: Can you show summarized, but representative code in the question? The lists "don't have a variable associated with them" but then how are they created?

Comment: You can return multiple values from your function. They are returned as a tuple

Answer (score 1):

Assign a variable to a function. Taking the lists the function generated, join them together in another variable. Just make sure that your function *returns* the generated list, and doesn't just print it out.

```
# my_list_generator returns two values.

>>> a, b = my_list_generator()
>>> a
[1, 2, 3, 4]
>>> b
[2, 0, 5, 6]
>>> final_list = a + b
>>> final_list
[1, 2, 3, 4, 2, 0, 5, 6]
```

Cross all that out! Now that I know the function can return multiple objects, let do this (with a little list comprehension):

```
lists = [i for i in my_list_generator()]
# lists might look like [[1, 2, 3, 4], [2, 0, 5, 6]]
# And now use a for loop to get each value

final_list = []
for sublist in lists:
    final_list.extend(sublist)
# final_list will look like [1,2,3,4,2,0,5,6]
```

Also, if you don't want duplicates, just do one more thing:

```
real_final_list = [i for i in final_list if i not in real_final_list]
```

Comment: They are generated in same function.

Comment: Sorry, the two lists (`a` and `b`) are generated in the same function? So that the function that generates the random lists returns *two* lists, and not just one?

Comment: @Zizouz212 Your question is not clear. Please clarify what you have actually.

Comment: @Marcin Sorry, I just realized that... :/

Comment: Sorry for my bad English. Yes the two lists a and b are generated in the same function.

Comment: That's okay! Don't worry about it. I'll make an edit to my question to clarify! :)

Comment: @amy Please provide minimal working example of this function.

Comment: Even the list comprehension is unnecessary. Just loop over the function's returned tuple in your for-loop. Also, your `real_final_list` won't work, you're referencing it before it has been defined.

Comment: @Petzku that's true that it is not completely necessary, and you can do the same thing in for loops. Really though, list comprehension still kind of uses for loops.

Answer (score 1):

```
def somefunc(param):
    #does something
    return alist,blist

my_alist,my_blist = somefunc(myparam)
print my_alist, my_blist
#prints both lists.
```

When you return multiple values from a function they are returned in a tuple. You can easily unpack the tuple

Answer (score 1):

You can either modify the function which is generating output, or the harder way being you manually convert it into a string and then into a set.

```
list = []
strings_of_list = output.split('\n')
for string in strings_of_list:
    values = string[1:-1].split(',')
    for val in values:
        list+=[int(val)]    
set(list)
```

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly:
You have a function (let's call it `listGen()` for now) which returns some number of lists. Now, you want to put these list together into one big list, `final_list`.

You could do the following:

```
# listGen defined earlier

final_list = []
for i in listGen():
    final_list += i

unique_values = set(final_list) # or whatever you wanted to do with it
```

Since `listGen` returns a tuple, we can loop over its contents, those being the lists you want to append to each other.